# MySQL character set for multiple European languages + mathematic symbols

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, character, collation

I need some help getting a MySQL table to store and output characters from the following languages:

- English
- French
- Russian
- Turkish
- German

These are the languages I know of in the data. It also uses mathematical symbols such as this:

> b ∈ A. Define s(A):= supn≥0 r A (n) for each A ⊆ ? ∪ {0}.

I'm using htmlentities to encode the text. The **?** above is meant to display as a **ℕ**.
It displays this way when I look at the data in PhpMyAdmin. The other characters are encoded as expected.

The table is set to **utf8_unicode_ci** and all aspects of the website have been set to **UTF-8** (including via the .htaccess file, a PHP header and a meta tag).

Please help?

Additional info:

Hosting environment:

```
Linux, Apache
Mysql 5.5.38 
PHP Version 5.4.4-14
```

Connection string :

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_host , $DB_username, $DB_password);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->select_db($DB_name);
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE mydatabase.mytable output:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ppub` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `pubdate` date NOT NULL,
 `numerous_other_tinytext_cols` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `numerous_other_tinytext_cols` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `keywords` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `src` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17780 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA output:

```
DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME
utf8 [->UTF-8 Unicode]
utf8mb4 [->UTF-8 Unicode]
```

Fonts used:

```
Arial
```

Sample of text in the database:

```
Let &lt;em&gt;A&lt;/em&gt; be a subset of the set of nonnegative integers ℕ &cup; {0}, and let &lt;em&gt;r&lt;/em&gt;&lt;sub&gt;&lt;em&gt;A&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/sub&gt; (&lt;em&gt;n&lt;/em&gt;) be the number of representations of &lt;em&gt;n&lt;/em&gt; &ge; 0 by the sum &lt;em&gt;a&lt;/em&gt; + &lt;em&gt;b&lt;/em&gt; with &lt;em&gt;a, b&lt;/em&gt; &isin; &lt;em&gt;A&lt;/em&gt;.
```

Output on web page:

```
Let <em>A</em> be a subset of the set of nonnegative integers ? ∪ {0}, and let <em>r</em><sub><em>A</em></sub> (<em>n</em>) be the number of representations of <em>n</em> ≥ 0 by the sum <em>a</em> + <em>b</em> with <em>a, b</em> ∈ <em>A</em>.
```

Which becomes

Let A be a subset of the set of nonnegative integers ? ∪ {0}, and let rA (n) be the number of representations of n ≥ 0 by the sum a + b with a, b ∈ A.

Comment: What is the connection string for the database? What do `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydatabase.mytable` and `SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA` say? What font(s), browser and operating system are you using? And finally, how does data in the database look like when you look at it via a DB client?

Comment: Hi Karol, I added some info above. Browsers checked so far include Firefox, IE 11 and Chrome. All output the same way.

Comment: Interestingly I noticed that the ℕ character doesn't display on this page when viewing this thread on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your database and table are configured to use UTF-8, one of your columns still isn't:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ppub` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `pubdate` date NOT NULL,
 `numerous_other_tinytext_cols` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `numerous_other_tinytext_cols` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `keywords` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `src` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,  <--------- This one
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17780 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Since all the other symbols got HTML-encoded, they will survive all charsets, but not `ℕ`, which doesn't have a named entity reference.

You need to convert your column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY src TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**NOTE:** I noticed you like mathematical symbols. Some of them are outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane, ie. have codepoints > 0xFFFF, for example [mathematical letter variants (fraktur, double-struck, semantic italic etc.)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf).

If you want to support them, you need to switch encoding in MySQL everywhere (table, columns, connection) to `utf8mb4`, which is the true UTF-8 (`utf8` in MySQL means the subset of UTF-8 with BMP only), with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. [Here is how to do the migration.](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

---

Also, I have noticed that you are HTML-encoding HTML. Maybe you have a reason, but in my opinion storing this doesn't make sense:

```
&lt;em&gt;A&lt;/em&gt;
```

If you want to put it into an HTML document, now you need to HTML-decode it at least once, sometimes twice. I'd rather store what almost everybody else does:

```
<em>A</em>
```

This way, you will store Unicode characters natively, in optimal way.

Comment: Thanks this sorted it out!

Comment: thanks for this, this is the only solution that worked for me.